# iOS App Submission : Where will Marketing URL appear?

Tags: ios, app-store

There is an entry "Marketing URL (Optional)" in iOS App Submission form. The tooltip description is:

> A URL with information about the app you are adding. If provided, this
>   will be visible to customers on the App Store.

After looked into Apple's documentation, it does not mention where will it appear. Also, I randomly checked few popular apps in App Store, I'm still uncertain which link is a Marketing URL . Can you guys advise ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this app: [NTQZ](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ntqz/id564851421?ls=1&mt=8)

Here, [IPhoneGameZone Web Site](http://www.iphonegamezone.net/your-own-ios-quiz/) is the marketing URL.

And [NTQZ - Funny General Knowledge Geogrpahy Science Trivia Quiz for kids Support](http://www.iphonegamezone.net/) is the support URL.

Comment: surprisingly, the Marketing URL does not appear in iTunes.

Comment: Yes, this is probably for SEO reasons only that you see it in browser.

Comment: What about in the app store on a phone? All i see is a button for developer website

Answer (score 8):

In the "iTunes Store Web Page" both the marketing URL and the support URL, if specified, will appear under the "App description" section. The support URL will appear as "Support for ", while the Marketing URL will appear as "Web site of ".

In the "iTunes App" the two URLs, plus the "Privacy URL", will appear on the left (below the icon) in the LINKS section (the marketing URL will be called "Developer Web Site".

A similar (but more visible) link to "Developer Web Site" is in the "App Store section" of the devices.